# How to configure HTTPS traffic from ALB to Backend IIS Website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have windows Ec2 instance hosting a web site in IIS and also using ALB. I have following configuration in AWS

`https://mywebsite.mydomain.com -> Application Load Balancer -> Listener (443) -> Target Group -> Windows Ec2 Instance (IIS)`

I have SSL certificate configured on ALB so that all the requests from users are always on HTTPS. However, the internal traffic from ALB to Ec2 is on port 80 (HTTP)

I want to configure internal traffic (ALB -> EC2) on HTTPS using self signed certificate. I can create a self signed certificate and configure in IIS. However, I am not sure what base route the target group is using to forward the traffic to instance? Does it use private ip or machine name or something else? What should be the value for dns name for the certificate?

```
$dnsname= "xxxxxx"
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "$dnsname" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Here is terraform for the target group

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "https" {
  name        = "my-tg-https"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  target_type = "instance"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  deregistration_delay = var.deregistration_delay

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    interval            = 30
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 5
    matcher             = 200
    port                = 443
    protocol            = "HTTPS"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Your target group should configure the port and the protocol, which it already does. It will use the private ip to talk to the server. As far as the self signed certificate goes, you should use the hostname

Comment: That's the question. What should be the hostname here? The main host name , "mywebsite.mydomain.com', is already configured in cert that is attached to  ALB.

Comment: Your EC2 instance is hosting in IIS, I think the dnsname is the hostname of your site in IIS. You could refer to [this method](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/aws-application-load-balancer/).